# Spring MVC mapping view for Google-GSON?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, gson

Does anyone know if there is a Spring MVC mapping view for [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? I'm looking for something similar to [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html).

Ideally it would take my ModelMap and render it as JSON, respecting my renderedAttributes set in the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver declaration

We plan to use Gson extensively in the application as it seems safer and better than Jackson. That said, we're getting hung up by the need to have two different JSON libraries in order to do native JSON views.

Thanks in advance!

[cross-posted to [Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=320106)]

Comment: Care to elaborate on "seems safer and better"? As in, better in what way? (or safer, for that matter)

Comment: +1, exactly what I was looking for as well.

Comment: For anyone who came here as of Spring boot 5.0, check my answer [force spring to use GSON, instead of Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459787/6860188)

Answer (score 11):

aweigold got me most of the way there, but to concretely outline a solution for Spring 3.1 Java based configuration, here's what I did.

Grab [GsonHttpMessageConverter.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android/blob/master/spring-android-rest-template/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/GsonHttpMessageConverter.java) from the [spring-android-rest-template](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android/tree/master/spring-android-rest-template) project.

Register your `GsonHttpMessageConverter` with the message converters in your MVC config.

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
  }
}
```

The Spring docs outline this process, but aren't crystal clear.  In order to get this to work properly, I had to extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, and then override `configureMesageConverters`.  After doing this, you should be able to do the following in your controller method:

```
@Controller
public class AppController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "messages", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public List<Message> getMessages() {
    // .. Get list of messages
    return messages;
  }
}
```

And voila!  JSON output.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me! With Spring 3.2.2 and jackson I could not get rid of the problem where it says: 406 not accaptable. I did this and it worked, but I also had to add <context:annotation-config/> to the service xml file.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to extend AbstractView just like the MappingJacksonJsonView does.

Personally, for JSON, I prefer to use @Responsebody, and just return the object rather than a model and view, this makes it easier to test.  If you would like to use GSON for that, just create a custom HttpMessageConverter like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.vitalimages.string.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Component
public class GSONHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

    public static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    private GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
            .registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new GSONTimestampConverter());

    public GSONHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(new MediaType("application", "json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        // should not be called, since we override canRead/Write instead
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(mediaType);
    }

    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith(mediaType);
    }

    public void registerTypeAdapter(Type type, Object serializer) {
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(type, serializer);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        try {
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            return    gson.fromJson(StringUtils.convertStreamToString(inputMessage.getBody()), clazz);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        Type genericType = TypeToken.get(o.getClass()).getType();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputMessage.getBody(), DEFAULT_CHARSET));
        try {
            // See http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=199 for details on SQLTimestamp conversion
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            writer.append(gson.toJson(o, genericType));
        } finally {
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And then add it to your converter list in your handler adapter like this:

```
@Bean
public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
    final AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
    handlerAdapter.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterList = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(handlerAdapter.getMessageConverters()));
    converterList.add(jibxHttpMessageConverter);
    converterList.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);
    handlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(converterList.toArray(new HttpMessageConverter<?>[converterList.size()]));
    return handlerAdapter;
}
```

Comment: Can you do the same thing with the bean but in the `applicationContext.xml`?