# Spring MVC 4: "application/json" Content Type is not being set correctly

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, content-type

I have a controller mapped with the following annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String bar() {
    return "{\"test\": \"jsonResponseExample\"}";
}
```

I return a valid JSON string however, the content-type when I view the response on Chrome Dev Tools in browser is not `application/json` but just plain `text/html`. Why is the content type not being set?

My `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- static assets -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

My `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Using WildFly 8.1 as my app server.

Comment: Do you use @ResponseBody and acctualy have some Json mapper ?

Comment: Let's see the rest of your method, your request headers and full response.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Added it all.

Comment: Add your jackson jar version and springMVC config for jackson.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

First thing to understand is that the [`RequestMapping#produces()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) element in

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

serves only to restrict the mapping for your request handlers. **It does nothing else.**

Then, given that your method has a return type of `String` and is annotated with `@ResponseBody`, the return value will be handled by [`StringHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/StringHttpMessageConverter.html) which sets the `Content-type` header to `text/plain`. If you want to return a JSON string yourself and set the header to `application/json`, use a return type of `ResponseEntity` (get rid of `@ResponseBody`) and add appropriate headers to it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> bar() {
    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"test\": \"jsonResponseExample\"}", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

---

Note that you should probably have

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your servlet context configuration to set up your MVC configuration with the most suitable defaults.

Answer (score 5):

Use jackson library and `@ResponseBody` annotation on return type for the Controller.

This works if you wish to return POJOs represented as JSon. If you woud like to return String and not POJOs as JSon please refer to Sotirious answer.

Comment: I did do that yet it still doesn't work. Could it be something to do with my config XML files? Used Gson instead of Jackson but same thing.

Comment: Add more details then please, show us your dependency and entire code for the controller.

Comment: I cannot speak about this Gson, i guarantee you that the jackson does work although.

Comment: This might be relevant for gson : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754055/spring-mvc-mapping-view-for-google-gson , but looks like more effort then jackson which works out of the box.

Comment: It is not the configuration files, the issue is with Gson. Could you try to exclude it and replace with jackson to test this thesis ?

Comment: This link shows how to achieve content type Json for Strings in context of jacskon library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507064/return-literal-json-strings-in-spring-mvc-responsebody

Answer (score 5):

As other people have commented, because the return type of your method is `String` Spring won't feel need to do anything with the result.

If you change your signature so that the return type is something that needs marshalling, that should help:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> bar() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("test", "jsonRestExample");
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I upgraded to Spring 4 I needed to update the jackson dependencies as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the dependencies as specified @Greg post. I still faced the issue and could be able to resolve it by adding following additional jackson dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly for this OP, but for those who encountered 404 and cannot set response `content-type` to `"application/json"` (any `content-type`). One possibility is a server actually responds 406 but explorer (e.g., chrome) prints it as 404.

If you do not customize message converter, spring would use `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java`. It would run:

```
List<MediaType> requestedMediaTypes = getAcceptableMediaTypes(request);
List<MediaType> producibleMediaTypes = getProducibleMediaTypes(request, valueType, declaredType);
```

and if they do not have any overlapping (the same item), it would throw `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` and this finally causes 406. No matter if it is an ajax, or GET/POST, or form action, if the request uri ends with a `.html` or any suffix, the `requestedMediaTypes` would be "text/[that suffix]", and this conflicts with `producibleMediaTypes`, which is usually:

```
"application/json"  
"application/xml"   
"text/xml"          
"application/*+xml" 
"application/json"  
"application/*+json"
"application/json"  
"application/*+json"
"application/xml"   
"text/xml"          
"application/*+xml"
"application/xml"  
"text/xml"         
"application/*+xml"
```

Comment: How to customize AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor?