# How to get both String body and object mapped from JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a controller to handle requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"", "/create"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody SomeRequest body, 
                                     HttpServletRequest request) {
    //...
}
```

It turned out I need both object mapped from JSON and request body as String value, to add it to response body in JSON format. My question is - is it possible with keeping current validation and mapping method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC 4: "application/json" Content Type is not being set correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548822/spring-mvc-4-application-json-content-type-is-not-being-set-correctly)

Comment: You can out put the object without converting to string, spring will just handle the conversion from controller, using jackson. If thats what you mean.

Comment: Ok, you're right, guys. Works perfectly. Should have tried it before. Thank you!