# Can not send JSON using POST request

Tags: java, json, spring, post

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> create(
        @RequestBody Category category) {

    if (categoryService.create(category)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

This is my config:

```
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="ru.tenet.cafe" />
```

This is Category class:

```
private Integer id;

private String title;

private String engTitle;

private String description; 

private List<MenuItem> menuItems;   

public Category()
{

}
public Category(Integer id, String title, String engTitle,
        String description, List<MenuItem> menuItems) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.engTitle = engTitle;
    this.description = description;
    this.menuItems = menuItems;
}

// getters and setters
```

If I try send post request with Content-type:application/json and the following body:

> {"id":8,"title":"Пицца","engTitle":"Pizza","description":null,"menuItems":[{"id":4,"title":"Пепперони","engTitle":"Pepperoni","price":300.0,"description":"Сами
>   лючщи пица слющи. Тольки щто привезли дарагой.","consistOf":"E666,
>   стальная стружка, вода (без
>   ГМО)","volumeValue":500.0,"volumeTitle":"г"},{"id":5,"title":"Маргарита","engTitle":"Margarita","price":400.0,"description":"Сами
>   сочни пица слющи. Мамай клянус.","consistOf":"Перец, сыр, колбаска,
>   ногти","volumeValue":500.0,"volumeTitle":"г"},{"id":6,"title":"Кавказ","engTitle":"Kavkaz
>   ji est","price":300.0,"description":"Вах пица. Сам ем
>   дарагой.","consistOf":"Ароматизатор \"Гусь\" идентичный
>   натуральному","volumeValue":500.0,"volumeTitle":"г"}]}

I will get :

> HTTP Status 415. The server refused this request because the request
>   entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
>   requested method.

What is wrong?

**UPD:**
Adding this 
`@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = "application/json")` gives me the same result

Comment: Add  `produces = "application/json"` in @RequestMapping. Also add header in request while requesting

Comment: add `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in `@RequestMapping` annotation

Comment: Doesn't help. The same thing.

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan, what kind of header? Content-type?

Comment: Yes. Add the Content-Type in request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem

I removed @RequestBody and instead used String. In your case it will be @Requestparam String category

Now category will be String of JSON format. Now use a json desrializer and deserialize the json

**Note:** I admit this is not the solution to your current problem but this is an alternate solution

Comment: @Tony did you do as I said?

Comment: By default it should work if Content-Type is there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548822/spring-mvc-4-application-json-content-type-is-not-being-set-correctly

Comment: @SpringLearner, I will try. I must add org.json jar and create new constructor that comsumes json.