# How to pass Object from angular js to Spring controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Angular Js method

```
$scope.Register = function(){
        userProfile = {};
        userProfile.usrName = $scope.usrName;
        userProfile.email = $scope.email;
        userProfile.pswd = $scope.pswd;
        userProfile.confirmpswd = $scope.confirmpswd;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(userProfile));
        $http.post('registerUser.htm', JSON.stringify(userProfile)).then(function mySuccess(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            alert($scope.myWelcome);
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
            alert($scope.myWelcome);
        });
```

Spring MVC Controller method

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

    @RequestMapping(headers = {"Accept=application/json"}, value = "/registerUser.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String login(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile){
        String message = "Hi Im here";
        try{
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
            UserProfile userProfile2= (UserProfile)context.getBean("userProfile") ;

            System.out.println(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

This always takes me to the failure method in Js and alerts 'Unsupported Media type' please help me with this.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548822/spring-mvc-4-application-json-content-type-is-not-being-set-correctly#answer-30549204) help?

Comment: userProfile = {}; instead of try  userProfile = [];  and push values as describe userProfile.push({
    usrName :$scope.usrName;
    email "$scope.email;
    pswd:$scope.pswd;
    confirmpswd = $scope.confirmpswd;
        
    });