# Spring REST Endpoint Returning String instead of JSON

Tags: rest, spring-security

The following endpoint returns a username as a string.

How would I structure it to return a json object that contains a key with that string as its value (e.g., {"user":"joeuser"}?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getUser", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> getUser() {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    CustomUserAuthentication authentication = (CustomUserAuthentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(responseHeaders).body(String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some Json library (like gson), build the Json object and return it in the body instead of the String.  Make sure response content-type is application/json

You can also manually build the String that looks like Json but content to must be as above.

Comment: Thanks, AlexC. I should clarify - I'd prefer not to use an additional library. Wondering if Spring has something like that I can leverage.

Answer (score 1):

Spring can do what you want, but you need to return something that Spring needs to marshal into JSON. From my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563674/48229

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> bar() {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("test", "jsonRestExample");
    return map;
}
```