# Force Spring-Boot to use Gson instead of Jackson

Tags: spring-boot

Spring-Boot 1.4.2 reference claims:

> spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jackson # Preferred JSON mapper to use for HTTP message conversion. Set to "gson" to force the use of Gson

We did it.

- We set gson for preferred-json-mapper.
- We have added Gson as dependency of our project.

But still Jackson was used.

Finally we manage to force Spring-Boot to use Gson after exclude all transitive dependencies in Maven which have been pointing out to Jackson.

Now the question is. Is it the only way to force Spring-Boot to use Gson instead of Jackson? Do we really need to exclude all transitive dependencies pointing out to Jackson? The preferred-json-mapper setting is not enough?

Comment: To avoid anyone wasting time trying to answer this, there's also a Spring Boot issue for it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7518

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred that in part of our old *.xml config which was used by Spring Boot we had `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`.

It was causing creation of RequestMappingHandlerAdapter 2nd time with default converters without GsonHttpMessageConverter.

Answer (score 12):

Well, `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is *deprecated*. As of **Spring 5.0** do this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public Gson gson() {
        GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
        b.registerTypeAdapterFactory(HibernateProxyTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
        b.registerTypeAdapterFactory(DateTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
        b.registerTypeAdapterFactory(TimestampTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
        b.registerTypeAdapterFactory(LocalDateTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
        b.registerTypeAdapterFactory(LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
        return b.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
        stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections
            .singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        converters.add(stringConverter);
        converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
        GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        gsonHttpMessageConverter.setGson(gson());
        gsonHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays
            .asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        converters.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But why all those factories? They require additional dependencies, yet even just with the DateTypeAdapter (included with Gson) this solution seems to have worked for me...

Comment: Nice, but I would go with [`extendMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#extendMessageConverters-java.util.List-). `This may be useful for example to allow default converters to be registered and then insert a custom converter through this method.`

Comment: Before adding the GsonHttpMessageConverter, you must remove the existing Jackson based convertor if present by using ```converters.removeIf(itm -> itm.getSupportedMediaTypes().contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));```

Answer (score 1):

F.e.
1) to add other json artifact, if using maven and google json named gson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>${latestGsonVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

2) to set

```
spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
```

3) to use it in code, for instance

```
@Autowired private Gson gson;
```

There are other ones as well:
Jackson Library, Google-Gson Library, JSON-lib, Flexjson, json-io, genson, JSONiJ Library.

Comment: not working. I can read this exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException, Note: this exception not relevant with this post. Just I see active converter library.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Spring source. You have to **exclude** `Jackson` from dependencies at all. I couldn't find where `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper` is used.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7518

```java
public class AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter extends FormHttpMessageConverter {

    private static final boolean jaxb2Present;

    private static final boolean jackson2Present;

    private static final boolean jackson2XmlPresent;

    private static final boolean jackson2SmilePresent;

    private static final boolean gsonPresent;

    private static final boolean jsonbPresent;

    static {
        ClassLoader classLoader = AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class.getClassLoader();
        jaxb2Present = ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.xml.bind.Binder", classLoader);
        jackson2Present = ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper", classLoader) &&
                        ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator", classLoader);
        jackson2XmlPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper", classLoader);
        jackson2SmilePresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileFactory", classLoader);
        gsonPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("com.google.gson.Gson", classLoader);
        jsonbPresent = ClassUtils.isPresent("javax.json.bind.Jsonb", classLoader);
    }


    public AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter() {
        try {
            addPartConverter(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
        }
        catch (Error err) {
            // Ignore when no TransformerFactory implementation is available
        }

        if (jaxb2Present && !jackson2XmlPresent) {
            addPartConverter(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
        }

        // THIS IS HERE
        if (jackson2Present) {
            addPartConverter(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        }
        else if (gsonPresent) {
            addPartConverter(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
        }
        else if (jsonbPresent) {
            addPartConverter(new JsonbHttpMessageConverter());
        }

        if (jackson2XmlPresent) {
            addPartConverter(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
        }

        if (jackson2SmilePresent) {
            addPartConverter(new MappingJackson2SmileHttpMessageConverter());
        }
    }

}
```