# Is it possible to have Jackson ObjectMapper to obey JAXB XML annotations in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson, jaxb

Having a [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) application using [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson) `ObjectMapper` I am using the following pattern to have a `List` field serialized nicely:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = true, localName = "items")    
private List<Item> items;
```

so to get something like:

```
<items>
   <item>...</item>
   <item>...</item>
   ...
</items>
```

I have studied - without any luck - how it would be possible to use [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb) annotations like `@XmlElementWrapper` to achieve this.

Is there - for example - something I can do with `JacksonConfiguration`?

**UPDATE**

Adding

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

to Spring JacksonConfiguration and annotating like:

```
@XmlElementWrapper
@XmlElement(name="item")
private List<Item> items;
```

does not work as expected. I am currently investigating possibility to replace Jackson with GSON as done in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40786366/6413377)

I would really like to have this annotation stuff to be generic so not just [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson) specific or like adding annotations per serializer implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried [jackson-dataformat-xml / JaxbAnnotationModule](https://stackify.com/java-xml-jackson/) and I'm not sure that it is compatible with spring-boot (you should write back if it is), but it would worth to test it.

**Update**:

Here you are a test (using the link above)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;



public class TestJacksonWithJaxbAnnot {

    static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    static  {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "item")
    static class Item {
        @XmlElement
        int id;
        @XmlElement
        String name;

        //getters, setters, etc.
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "itemcollection")
    static class ItemCollection {
        @XmlElement
        String nameOfItems;
        @XmlElement
        List<Item> items;

        //getters, setters, etc.
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
        ItemCollection testColl = new ItemCollection();
        testColl.nameOfItems = "Test items";
        Item item1 = new Item();
        item1.id = 1;
        item1.name = "apple";
        Item item2 = new Item();
        item2.id = 2;
        item2.name = "orange";
        testColl.items = Arrays.asList(item1, item2);

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamWriter sw =     xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringWriter);
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

        sw.writeStartDocument();
        sw.writeStartElement("root");

        mapper.writeValue(sw, testColl);

        sw.writeComment("Some insightful commentary here");
        sw.writeEndElement();
        sw.writeEndDocument();
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <ItemCollection>
      <nameOfItems>Test items</nameOfItems>
      <items>
         <items>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>apple</name>
         </items>
         <items>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>orange</name>
         </items>
      </items>
   </ItemCollection>
   <!--Some insightful commentary here-->
</root>
```

As you can see, it is not perfect, e.g. it did not handle the defined names in @XmlRootElement annotations. (Tested in my 1.5.10.RELEASE spring-boot project, where the jackson-dataformat-xml has 2.8.10 managed version).

Maybe with later versions you would get better output.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Although I think somenone will flag this as a 'link only answer' (more suitable as an comment). I checked the configuration of the project I am using and it actually includes version 2.9.5 of jackson-dataformat-xml, I'll check further if the link you procided gives me details how to get ObjectMapper to really use that ability.

Comment: I would usually create two different DTO for this, because it can easily turn out that you need to use different representation for JSON/XML and in this case your effort to beeing simple/centralized etc. will be in vain, on top of that this feature is not that well known that JAXB/Jackson for JSON, maybe it is not that battle proof that one would expect.

Comment: The output for a `List<Item>` you presented is the default output so without any annotations. I will update my question soon.