# replaced jackson with gson in spring MVC Application( not using spring boot ) but still getting error for jackson dependency

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, gson

**I  have created a POC to support gson instead of jackson with Spring MVC 5 and Java 8  but not using Spring Boot .** 

 
[Reference tutorial](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/023-configure-integrate-gson-spring-boot/)

*Even after removing jackson binding support from pom.xml and using gson, gives error:*

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
```

Pom.xml entry :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>
```

@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter customConverters() {

    Collection<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();

    GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverters.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);

    return gsonHttpMessageConverter;
}
```

}

```
Dependency Graph 
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Comment: pom.xml entries

Comment: Please take a look into the dependency graph of your project (eg. by using mvn dependency:tree), all dependencies incl. the transient ones, should be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the help . i have checked the dependency graph of my project , gson dependencies are already present .

Comment: [INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile

Comment: Jackson dependencies are not present in the dependency graph still i am getting the error . Can you please help regarding the same .

Comment: Spring is still looking for the class, so probably Spring tries to use it still.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786366/force-spring-boot-to-use-gson-instead-of-jackson

Answer (score 1):

Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459787/10099219) from reference given by @triplem earlier would help you. Its using Spring 5.0 not Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Deepika for posting this question on our behalf.
Responding to old thread, but here is the problem and how we resolved it.

**Problem**
Even though we removed all Jackson dependencies from pom.xml and configured Spring to use GSON rather than Jackson for serialization and de-serialization, the container was trying to load some Jackson classes and as a result, throwing the above exception. The reason is that we were using **JBoss-EAP-7**. Jboss tries to load Resteasy module while application runtime (JAX-RS, JSR-311, is a new JCP specification that provides a Java API for RESTful Web Services over the HTTP protocol) When we look carefully in its module.xml (location: EAP-7.1.0\modules\system\layers\base\com\fasterxml\jackson\jaxrs\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider\main), we can see that it requires "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" dependency. So, Jboss throws exception when it is unable to find this JAR in lib.

**Solution 1:**
If you are not using Jboss's Resteasy implementation in your project, then just exclude that module from Jboss.
Create file jboss-deployment-structure.xml within WEB-INF (for a JBoss WAR project, this location is same as that of jboss-web.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
                <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
       </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**Solution 2:**
Open the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider's module.xml (path mentioned above). And comment out the jackson-databind entry below:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider">
     <resources>
        <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.9.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.9.redhat-1.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.9.redhat-1.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
        <!--<module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>-->
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Both the above solutions work perfectly (we have tested); they tell Spring container not to load the Jackson modules if Jackson is not present in classpath dependency.

Hope this helps others!